# UIScrollView, pagingEnabled, scrolling inertia, and sub sections of the UIView width

Tags: objective-c, uiview, uiscrollview, custom-scrolling

In my app I'm using a scrolling canvas composed of equally sized cells.
The number of rows is unlimited, but the number of columns is fixed to 13.
At anyone time, I have exactly 7 cells fitting the width of the view.

I wrote my own tiling UIScrollView and everything is fine and works fine except for one thing:
I want to enable "paging" on the cell boundary, not on the "page" boundary.

In other words I want the horizontal scrolling to move no more than "one cell at a time". This is a usability issue.

In a standard UIScrollView with pagingEnabled=YES, there is some inertia when moving from one page to the next, but then the page is defined as having the full width of the view. I want to define the notion of page as 1/7 of the view width, such that I get the same kind of inertia when moving the display from cells 1-7 to cells 2-8, to cells 3-9, etc...

How would I go about that?

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11966914/uiscrollview-setting-page-size-dynamically) and [this, but this a related but different problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6945964/uiscrollview-custom-paging).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Try making your scrollview less than the size of the screen (width-wise), but uncheck the 'Clip Subviews' checkbox in IB."

More info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1677400/427083).